# how to click a link inside iframe

Tags: javascript, wordpress, translate

I want to click on a link inside iframe onload with the help of JavaScript, I have a site loading inside an iframe, now I want to click a link of a particular div (ID) on page load. The link is inside the iframe.

Actually I'm trying to change the language of the website which is loading in the iframe, the site has gtranslate plugin installed and has different language flag at the footer of the site.

Basically is it possible to force a page to be translated when the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

The **Same Origin Policy** prevents you from scripting an Iframe from a different domain.

Possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11108056/4811421)

Comment: Is it possible to click a link inside iframe or not. I'm not able understand from the above link.