# How to click svg element within an iFrame using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, iframe

I am trying to use web automation and use JavaScript or JQuery to click the svg elements within an iFrame.
I am trying to click on all the svg elements with class "expand-svg".

Here is the website:  https://121fcu.org/careers/

Here is JQuery I tried using unsuccessfully:

```
var el = $("gnewtonIframe").contents().find("svg[class='expand-svg']");
el.trigger("click");
```

Here is JavaScript I tried using unsuccessfully:

```
document.querySelectorAll('svg[class="expand-svg"]')[0].click();
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click link inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101824/click-link-inside-iframe)

Comment: No, that post does not seem to have a solution.